# How to run a selected suiteXmlFile via maven surefire plugin

Tags: java, maven, testng, maven-surefire-plugin

I have gone through all related questions on SO. But I think my question is little different than others.

I have following suite xml files

**Initialize.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Start" verbose="1" parallel="tests"
    thread-count="5" configfailurepolicy="continue">


    <test name="Initialize" annotations="JDK" preserve-order="true">
        <parameter name="tags" value="not @42" />
        <classes>
            <class name="com.example.runner.InitializeExecution" />
        </classes>
    </test>

</suite>
```

**Conclude.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Start" verbose="1" parallel="tests"
    thread-count="5" configfailurepolicy="continue">

    <test name="Conclude" annotations="JDK" preserve-order="true">
        <parameter name="tags" value="not @42" />
        <classes>
            <class name="com.example.runner.ConcludeExecution" />
        </classes>
    </test>

</suite>
```

**smoke.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="smoke" verbose="1" parallel="tests"
    thread-count="3" configfailurepolicy="continue" data-provider-thread-count="2">


    <test name="Smoke" annotations="JDK" preserve-order="true">
        <parameter name="tags" value="@dm1" />
        <classes>
            <class name="com.example.runner.smoke" />
        </classes>
    </test>


</suite>
```

**regression.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="smoke" verbose="1" parallel="tests"
    thread-count="3" configfailurepolicy="continue" data-provider-thread-count="2">


    <test name="Regression" annotations="JDK" preserve-order="true">
        <parameter name="tags" value="@dm1" />
        <classes>
            <class name="com.example.runner.regression" />
        </classes>
    </test>


</suite>
```

**pom.xml snippets**

```xml
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.21.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <properties>
                            <property>
                                <name>dataproviderthreadcount</name>
                                <value>2</value>
                            </property>
                        </properties>
                        <suiteXmlFiles>
                            <suiteXmlFile>Initialize.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                            <suiteXmlFile>${suiteXmlFile}</suiteXmlFile>
                            <suiteXmlFile>Conclude.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                        </suiteXmlFiles>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
```

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
    <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
    <version>6.14.3</version>
    <!-- <scope>compile</scope> -->
</dependency>
```

I need to execute initialize.xml then either of smoke.xml or regression.xml then conclude.xml in sequential order.
Consider the following set as an example:

```xml
<suiteXmlFiles>
     <suiteXmlFile>Initialize.xml</suiteXmlFile>
     <suiteXmlFile>smoke.xml</suiteXmlFile>
               <!-- or -->
<!-- <suiteXmlFile>regression.xml</suiteXmlFile> -->
     <suiteXmlFile>Conclude.xml</suiteXmlFile>
</suiteXmlFiles>
```

How can I parameterize middle suiteXmlFile from pom? I tried using below command but its not working and throwing exception.

```
mvn clean test -Dsurefire.suiteXmlFile=smoke.test
```

```java
[ERROR] org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireExecutionException: Exception in provider
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.InPluginVMSurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcess(InPluginVMSurefireStarter.java:91)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeProvider(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1132)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAfterPreconditionsChecked(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:978)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.execute(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:854)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:154)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:146)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:305)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:192)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:105)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:956)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:290)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:194)
[ERROR]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[ERROR]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[ERROR]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[ERROR]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
[ERROR]     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
[ERROR]     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
[ERROR]     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
[ERROR]     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
[ERROR] Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGXmlTestSuite.locateTestSets(TestNGXmlTestSuite.java:97)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke(TestNGProvider.java:119)
[ERROR]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[ERROR]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[ERROR]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[ERROR]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray2(ReflectionUtils.java:206)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:160)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:83)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.InPluginVMSurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcess(InPluginVMSurefireStarter.java:87)
[ERROR]     ... 25 more
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

If I use below command it is working but not executing initialize.xml and conclude.xml (Note the **s** in command)

```
mvn clean test -Dsurefire.suiteXmlFiles=smoke.test
```

I have also tried creating different suite xml like below and passing it through command line but its not working as I expected.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">

 <suite name="Smoke Suite"  > 
    <suite-files>
           <suite-file path="./Initialize.xml" />
           <suite-file path="./somke.xml" />
           <suite-file path="./Conclude.xml" />
    </suite-files>
</suite>
```

Please help. Any references or helpful links also appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can we do something like below, most of which you have already done :

```
<suiteXmlFiles>
     <suiteXmlFile>Initialize.xml</suiteXmlFile>
     <suiteXmlFile>${smokeORregression}</suiteXmlFile>
     <suiteXmlFile>Conclude.xml</suiteXmlFile>
</suiteXmlFiles>
```

And then execute `mvn clean test -DsmokeORregression=smoke.xml` or `mvn clean test -DsmokeORregression=regression.xml` as per need.

You don't need `Surefire` in mvn command.